# reading from a file c++ [program halts at reading put]

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem reading in from a file, I feel disoriented and I cannot seem to find the error within my code(I'm sure it's a minor mistake because I've done this before) This a homework assignment. The assignment calls for the constructor to load in contents from a file. However, the program halts after reading in the first line.

```
tree::tree()
    {

    root = NULL;
    load();
}

int tree::load()
{
    ifstream inFile;

    definition anEntry;

    char title[TITLE], info[INFO];

    inFile.open("CS_terms.txt");

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        cin.get(title, TITLE, ':');
        cin.ignore(TITLE, ':');
        cin.get(info, INFO, '\n');
        cin.ignore(INFO, '\n'); 

        anEntry.createEntry(title, info);
        insert(anEntry);

        while (inFile.is_open() && !inFile.eof())
        {
            cin.get(title, TITLE, ':');
            cin.ignore(TITLE, ':');
            cin.get(info, INFO, '\n');
            cin.ignore(INFO, '\n'); 
            anEntry.createEntry(title, info);
            insert(anEntry);
        }
        inFile.close();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No File" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your root is NULL, and you are doing  root->entry...  wont work

Comment: Sorry, it should be this

   anEntry.createEntry(title, info);
        insert(anEntry);

Comment: `while (inFile && !inFile.eof())` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Looks like you dont need that redundant bit before the while loop, because its already inside the while loop.  That won't solve the problem, but will make it more straightforward.

Comment: Yeah, it still persists, I've updated my code slightly.
and drescherjm, I understand that it is bad to use, however, it doesn't even step into the loop. Program stops at cin.get(title, TITLE, ':'); the very first read, doesn't step to next line of code

Comment: Totally get that Bango, I've just been following coding style from my instructor it's kind of a "safety precaution", apparently, according to her.

Comment: See if it steps into the loop when you take out the part outside the loop.  Looks like you've narrowed down the problem to your cin.get()  statements.

Comment: Bango, it opens the file, however still same problem persists.

Comment: I don't know why your prof wants you to put that bit before the while loop.  Seems like the opposite of safety precaution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `cin.get()` with `inFile.get()`

Answer (score 1):

You should replace this line:

```
if (inFile)
```

by this

```
if (inFile.is_open())
```

and this:

```
while (inFile.is_open() && !inFile.eof())
```

by

```
while (inFile.good())
```

Comment: True, but it is open, because they are getting the first line.  Why would the file close unless close() is being called?

Comment: The problem exists with the first attempt to read in from the file.. could my text file be corrupt? If so, how can I check? OH and btw I've had a similar issue in the past, when transferring files from windows to linux, the new line character is associated as \r\n in windows

Comment: @HaiNguyen use cmd command:  `dos2unix CS_terms.txt` to pre process your text file in the linux console